# Django and Jquery Form plugin CRSF problem

Tags: jquery, django

Hi I am using JQuery Form Plugin for AJAX form submission in my web application and I am getting a problem with CSRF not being transferred to server side. I think the problem is that JQuery Form Plugin uses iframes for submitting form and the plugin is not using ajaxSetup option of JQuery. Can anyone help? Maybe some of you have faced with this kind of problem? THanks in advance!

Or is there any other pluging to easyly implement file uploads?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include {% csrf_token %}  in your form ...........and inyour javascript file....
put something like this in your function(click,onload etc) from which you want to call ajax

```
var csrfmiddlewaretoken = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;
dataString = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="+csrfmiddlewaretoken
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/to/view/",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response){
});
```

Comment: And since the Jquery Form Plugin says that you can use any of the standard ajax options with ajaxForm (assuimg thats what you are using) it will still work with your plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api